# Error on subcategories url key

Tags: magento-1.9, category, url-key

I am starting populating few items for test.

My subcategories list are only displaying one product if I go to subcategory url key. But the products count show the right total number on category or subcategory.

I have checked the items below

- the mysql config_data has {{unsecure_base_url}} and {{secure_base_url}}
- Removed the .html from Product URL Suffix and Category URL Suffix
- Category and Subcategry is enabled and show in navigation
- Use Categories Path for Product URLs and Create Permanent Redirect for URLs if URL Key Changed selected YES
- Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Products and Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Categories selected YES
- Maximal Depth 0
- I checked var/report and var/error nothing when I go to subcategory url key
- index.php is set to 1 to display errors and uncomment
- Target path gives me save error of display one product
- I have cleared cache of var/cache and refresh on admin
- Reindexed data
- Create Permanent Redirect for old URL checked

If I clicked root categories it shows all products from subcategories.
If I navigated through layered navigation Categories then Subcategories it shows all products.

But if I go to subcategory url key it only show 1 product.

What I am doing wrong? How can I fix it or see the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error was I did not enable the Category Product Count on cache management. I am using the Disable Empty Categories.